# Slicing an image array into sub array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

```
import numpy as np
import numpy as numpy
import cv2
from PIL import Image
from numpy import array
img = cv2.imread('image test.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img.cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
myArray = array(gray)
slice = myArray[:8,:8]
print slice
print myArray 
k = cv2.waitKey(0)
if k == 27:
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

This is my code for slicing an array of an image into 8*8 Block.i am trying to convert this array into an 8*8 matrix but it resulted a 3*8 matrix while running the above python code. Any information regarding this will be helpful.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
img = cv2.imread('image test.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img.cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
data = np.asarray(gray)
data = np.split(data, data.shape[0]/8)
res = []
for arr in data:
    res.extend(np.split(arr,arr.shape[1]/8, axis = 1)
    print res[0]
k = cv2.waitKey(0)
if k == 27:
    cv2.destroyAllWindows() 



[[6 6 6 6 5 5 6 6]
 [7 7 7 6 6 6 7 7]
 [8 7 7 7 7 8 8 8]
 [8 7 6 6 7 8 8 8]
 [7 6 5 6 6 7 7 7]
 [6 5 5 5 6 6 7 7]
 [6 5 5 5 6 6 7 8]
 [6 6 6 6 6 7 8 9]]
```

this output is repeated thrice.when print res[40] is given "list index out of range" as error is displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess your array i.e., `myArray` is of shape **3*n, n>=8**. This is the only possible reason for this behavior.

Demo:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.ones((16,16))
>>> slice = a[:8,:8]
>>> slice.shape
(8, 8)
>>> a = np.ones((3,16))
>>> slice = a[:8,:8]
>>> slice.shape
(3, 8)
```

Code to split the data into 8x8 sub-array:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> data = np.random.randint(0,10,size=(320,240)) # create a random array of 320x240
>>> data = np.split(data, data.shape[0]/8)  # first split into 8x240, 8x240,... sub-arrays, i.e., split by rows of 8 first.
>>> res = []
>>> for arr in data:
...     res.extend(np.split(arr,arr.shape[1]/8, axis=1)) # now for each 8x240 sub-array split it column-wise into 8x8, 8x8,... arrays
... 
>>> res[0]
array([[5, 7, 3, 0, 2, 7, 5, 2],
       [8, 1, 8, 6, 3, 8, 8, 5],
       [7, 4, 6, 7, 9, 5, 1, 6],
       [0, 2, 4, 3, 1, 2, 0, 3],
       [4, 4, 8, 8, 5, 7, 4, 2],
       [2, 0, 8, 2, 9, 8, 9, 3],
       [6, 4, 0, 3, 3, 3, 5, 8],
       [6, 2, 8, 5, 0, 5, 1, 3]])
       .
       .
       .
>>> res[1199]
array([[8, 5, 5, 9, 1, 7, 5, 4],
       [0, 1, 8, 0, 3, 8, 5, 9],
       [2, 5, 3, 6, 7, 2, 8, 8],
       [1, 1, 7, 0, 0, 4, 3, 1],
       [5, 5, 8, 6, 6, 6, 5, 7],
       [9, 4, 2, 2, 7, 2, 1, 1],
       [6, 9, 5, 2, 5, 9, 3, 4],
       [1, 8, 1, 9, 7, 6, 7, 0]])
```

Comment: but in actual my image i.e img is of 320x240 shape.so wen i create myArray how it is giving a shape of 3*n?

Comment: what does `img.shape` and `myArray.shape` result

Comment: `img = cv2.imread('image test.jpg')` results in a **numpy array**, so converting **numpy array** to **numpy array** using `myArray = array(img)` would never cause data loss. What I am trying to say is that `img` would also be of size 3*240. Thus `cv2.imread('image test.jpg')` is resulting in an image read of 3*240 size. Please check `img.shape`...

Comment: both are resulting as (240,320,3)

Comment: thanks the problem is solved by converting the image into grey scale.

Comment: i do have a doubt. when i give print slice, will it result into 1200 sub arrays of 8x8 block. How can we confirm it? because in the output all i can see is one 8x8 array and another array with remaining elements. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Creating all 1200 sub arrays of 8x8 block is a bit complex. I'll explain it in my answer. Check it out.

Comment: i have edited the code in the question. BUt i found some error while executing it. Could you please check the edited part.

Answer (score 0):

Replace these lines:

```
for arr in data:
    res.extend(np.split(arr,arr.shape[1]/8, axis = 1)
    print res[0]
```

with:

```
for arr in data:
    res.extend(np.split(arr,arr.shape[1]/8, axis = 1)

for i in res: print i
```